# Which iPhone apps to become more proficient speaker in foreign language?

Tags: iphone, ios, software-recommendation

I use Livemocha but it does not work with iPhone due to the lack of Flash. Which apps are good to learn pronunciation and articulation of foreign language?

Answer (score 1):

Voice Translator helps you check whether your pronunciation matches any known word.

- [Voice Translator](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/voice-translate-pro/id539943615?mt=8)

The BETA services are new but interesting.

- BETA [HelloTalk](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/hellotalk-language-exchange/id557130558?mt=8) (social network)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, user! Can you please add a link to the software you mention in your answer? It is always helpful to add a link to help the OP to find the right software. Thank you.